# Can I trade with any non-hostile base on the planet?

Tags: rimworld

I've read the wiki, dozens of Steam forum and Reddit threads but nothing answers questions about trading I have:

1. Do I have to wait for a trading request or can I force other bases to trade with me by just visiting them with a caravan?
2. If so, can I launch caravan in the pod on them directly or do I have to send it in the neighbour tile?
3. And after that can I add stuff to my caravan using pods while caravan is at the tile it's trading with?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely keep sending trade caravans to other factions, as this really allows you to keep up a good economy. You don't need to wait for a request.

> **Sending caravans out from your home, instead of just waiting for other tribes to come to you, helps keep up fluid commerce** ... It's also cheaper than requesting traders at the comms console.

[Source](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Caravan) (emphasis mine)

Sending transport pods can be directed at any tile you like. Sending it to a tile which has your caravan will add the resources to their stock. Sending it to a faction tile will prompt you to land it at the edge or the center.

> Pods can either be launched at a tile (including tiles owned by a faction), or at a caravan. **Selecting a faction base prompts to drop at the edge or drop at the center, whereas selecting a caravan allows you to add the contents of the pod to the target caravan.** Selecting a tile not occupied by a faction base will immediately launch the pod group.
>
> ...
>
> **Be careful with the landing site, as the pods can go through roofs**; while they don't deal any damage directly, the collapsing roof can damage nearby items.

[Source](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Transport_pod) (emphasis mine)

Comment: Again the second part is about cases when I drop onto my caravan and when I drop onto a camp, but not about when I drop onto my caravan that is visiting a camp. The map of camp tile will be opened only if I'm ambushing them, right? Then the dialog of where do I want to land would make sense. But I don't want to ambush, I want to trade.

Comment: Also: "Sending caravans out from your home helps keep up fluid commerce" -- when I init a trade they will have some limit of silver, right? Will this limit reset when I init another trade imediately? These processes are badly documented.

Comment: @Nakilon for your first comment, I can't say for sure. I would assume the resources get added to the caravan that is visiting the camp you are targeting. 
For your second comment: no, it will not reset immediately. I've seen sources claiming they "reset" once every season, but I have not confirmed this myself.